# Trying to loop to beginning of program

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

I don't know how to get the program to restart if the wrong input is given.

I am new to java and don't know how to effectively use if statements or loops.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class TuitionRates 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    //variables
    String name = "";
    String studentType = "";
    int creditNumber = 0;
    double totalTF = 0.00;
    double studentACTFee = 4.60;
    double parkingFee = 2.00;
    double tuition = 180.40;
    double capitalFee1 = 0.00;
    double capitalFee2 = 21.00;
    double perCreditR = 187.00;
    double perCreditV = 187.00;
    double perCreditD = 187.00;
    double perCreditM = 208.00;
    double perCreditB = 268.00;
    double perCreditO = 387.25;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Asking user for Name
System.out.println("Welcome to the NOVA Tuition and Fees Calculator.");
System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
name= input.nextLine();

//Ask user to choose option

    System.out.println("Please enter the type of student that your are from 
    the choices below:\n"
            + 
            "R for Virginia Resident\r\n" + 
            "M for Military Contract Out-of-State\r\n" + 
            "V for Military Veterans and Dependents\r\n" + 
            "D for Dual Enrolled\r\n" + 
            "B for Business Contract Students\r\n" + 
            "O for Out of State Students\r\n");

    studentType = input.nextLine();
if (studentType.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))
   {

   System.out.println("Please enter the number of credits that you are 
   taking:");
   creditNumber = input.nextInt();

if (creditNumber <= 18)
{
System.out.println("Tuition and fees report for " + name);          
System.out.println("Tuition: "+ tuition);           
System.out.println( "Capital Fee:  \t"+ capitalFee1);           
System.out.println( "Student Activities Fee: \t "+   studentACTFee);            
System.out.println( "Parking Infrastructure Fee: \t " +  parkingFee);           
System.out.println("Tuition & Fees Per Credit: " +  perCreditR);            
System.out.println("X Number of Credits: " + creditNumber);
totalTF = creditNumber * perCreditR;            
System.out.println("Total Tuition and Fees: \t" +  totalTF);
System.out.println("Bodly NOVA");
}

else {System.out.println("Please re-enter credit Number ");}
}
```

I want my program to restart the if statement if the number of credits is over 18.  So if I entered 19 it would say re-enter credits and start the if over.

Comment: `while(true)`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try wrapping your `if` statement in a `do-while` loop:

```
if (studentType.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))
{
    do{
       System.out.println("Please enter the number of credits that you are taking:");
       creditNumber = input.nextInt();

        if (creditNumber <= 18)
        {
            System.out.println("Tuition and fees report for " + name);          
            System.out.println("Tuition: "+ tuition);           
            System.out.println( "Capital Fee:  \t"+ capitalFee1);           
            System.out.println( "Student Activities Fee: \t "+   studentACTFee);            
            System.out.println( "Parking Infrastructure Fee: \t " +  parkingFee);           
            System.out.println("Tuition & Fees Per Credit: " +  perCreditR);            
            System.out.println("X Number of Credits: " + creditNumber);
            totalTF = creditNumber * perCreditR;            
            System.out.println("Total Tuition and Fees: \t" +  totalTF);
            System.out.println("Bodly NOVA");
        }
        else {System.out.println("Please re-enter credit Number ");}
    }while(creditNumber > 18);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`do-while` construct can be effective here.

```
if (studentType.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))
   {

   do {
       System.out.println("Please enter the number of credits that you are 
       taking:");
       creditNumber = input.nextInt();
       if(creditNumber > 18) System.out.println("Too many credits");
   while(creditNumber > 18);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
if (studentType.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))
{

System.out.println("Please enter the number of credits that you are 
taking:");
creditNumber = input.nextInt();

while(creditNumber > 18)
{
    System.out.println("Please re-enter the number of credits that you are 
    taking:");
    creditNumber = input.nextInt();
}

System.out.println("Tuition and fees report for " + name);          
System.out.println("Tuition: "+ tuition);           
System.out.println( "Capital Fee:  \t"+ capitalFee1);           
System.out.println( "Student Activities Fee: \t "+   studentACTFee);            
System.out.println( "Parking Infrastructure Fee: \t " +  parkingFee);           
System.out.println("Tuition & Fees Per Credit: " +  perCreditR);            
System.out.println("X Number of Credits: " + creditNumber);
totalTF = creditNumber * perCreditR;            
System.out.println("Total Tuition and Fees: \t" +  totalTF);
System.out.println("Bodly NOVA");
}
```

This uses a while() statement that checks if the initial creditNumber is greater then 18 and continually re-prompt the user for new input. Then once they provide a value less-then or equal to 18, it does all the other stuff you want it to do. Note, I didn't test this but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Well i could advise you to rethink the design. But that wasn't your question - right? So, if you realy want, what you asked for, here it is, a break("poor man exception"):

```
exitpoint:{

     //your code ...
     break exitpoint;
     //more code
     break exitpoint;
     //....
}
```

or with some loop:

```
exitpoint:
while( ){
    // code....
    for(;;){
        //...
        break exitpoint;
    }
}
```

A by far better way to handle errors(like wrong user input) are exceptions. But that wasn't the question either-  was it?

Comment: yeah, I know the way I wrote it wasn't efficient I'm new to java. I appreciate the help.

Comment: no sweat!  I was just poining out that my example is not necesarily a recomendation to design a program in this way.  (programs tend to get difficult to read if one jumps around). But everything can have its use .. .